# Empty GUID error when using Azure AD consent flow

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm currently trying to integrate with Azure AD using the admin consent flow.
I've set up an app in our domain, set a few permissions on it and am then navigating to the following link:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytestdomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://example.com/responsehandler&resource=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012&prompt=admin_consent&state=12345
```

(Some of the values here have been swapped out for "example" values)

When I navigate there I get asked to sign in, which I do using a different test domain into which I want to import the app.
After signing in I'm shown a list of all the permissions that the app needs (which appear to be correct), I click accept but then I get the following error:

```
AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.
```

I'm not sure where this empty GUID is coming from and after some searching I can't find any reference to what might be causing it.

Comment: any luck finding the solution for this?

Comment: Apparently Azure support are "looking into it", and will reply here.

Comment: I was trying to authenticate with the user that I used to create my Azure account (which is a Microsoft account). When I did the test with a user that I created for (and only existed in) my tenant, the token was successfully generated.

Comment: Happening to me as well. So is there a known issue with AAD right now? Strange timing for me as I am running through my very first tutorial on the subject!

Comment: Have you fixed this issue now? Based on the test, the admin consent works well for me now.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT we're still experiencing this issue, when trying to add our App into customers' AAD's.  This is a super critical issue for us, as currently, it is stopping us from onboarding any new signups to CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com -- how do we connect to resolve?

Comment: @Igorek I am able reproduced this issue now. I am trying to report this issue. As a temporary workaround to give the admin consent, please use the admin of Azure Active Directory account as Daniel mentioned.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Does not work.  For test purposes, I have a completely separate Azure subscription in a new AD.  When trying to create the Service Principal in it, from my production subscription/AD, and while being a Global Administrator in my test subscription, I get the error

Comment: @Igorek What's the detail error message when you grant the admin_consent using the admin account from that tenant?

Comment: AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.

Comment: To be more precise:

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 3d468788-b006-420a-a9b2-46f7685cf263
Timestamp: 2017-04-17 06:57:07Z
AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.

Comment: I do get the consent dialog to show up:

CloudMonix
App publisher website: cloudmonixoutlook.onmicrosoft.com
CloudMonix needs permission to:
Sign you in and read your profile  
Access Azure Service Management as you (preview)  
You're signed in as: xxxx@paraleap.com
Hide details
Your organization: Paraleap Technologies
Application published by: CloudMonix Directory
You should grant permission only if you trust the application publisher with your data, and if you selected this application from a store or website you trust. Ask your admin if you're not sure about granting permission.

Answer (score 2):

[Daniel Camargo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2251135/daniel-camargo)'s comment above seems to have done the trick.
When I navigated to the login.microsoftonline.com link I was logging in with the user that created the domain.
If I log in with a test admin user that I created it works as I'd want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that we had exactly the same problem, given that my case was involving a Cordova application, but I will share my scenario anyway:

I created a trial account for my proof of concept and for that I used my personal Microsoft account that I will call mypersonalaccount@outlook.com.

Thus, mypersonalaccount@outlook.com is now part of 2 directories: the outlook.com and my recently created mypersonalaccount.onmicrosoft.com.

When I was trying to authenticate in my Oauth2 application using mypersonalaccount@outlook.com I got that error. My humble guess is that the error is related to some sort of collision between the 2 accounts.

I later created a user1@mypersonalaccount.onmicrosoft.com and a guest account using my gmail account. Everything worked fine with these ones.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem, and the same after 1 week of work by the azure team, was solved.

My problem was being trying to log in to VSTS with AAD accounts.