# OpenIdConnect error - Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID

Tags: asp.net, azure, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm attempting to use the OWIN Open ID Connect middleware to outsource  authentication for my ASP.NET application to Azure Active Directory.  The application successfully redirects to the Azure AD sign-in page upon accessing a page that requires authorisation. However upon signing in to Azure AD I'm encountering the following error:

AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.

Here is the call to `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`. The tenant which is included in the Authority URL is f82d0e29-6018-43c6-b806-1f46a009ff4a. So why does Azure AD think I am passing in an empty GUID for the tenant?

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "AzureAd",
                Caption = "Office 365",
                Scope = "openid email profile",
                ClientId = "e34401b2-6a9f-4547-9229-f0d93a33b1a1",
                Authority = "https://login.windows.net/f82d0e29-6018-43c6-b806-1f46a009ff4a/",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:44333",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:44333",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
            });
```

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369841/empty-guid-error-when-using-azure-ad-consent-flow

Comment: I try to reproduce this issue however failed, please feel free to let me know if you still have this problem.

Comment: I'm still getting this error when trying to Aquire a token, even for a new user. Check correlationId fdd189bb-f220-4e93-9e66-9aa7649d08a4

Answer (score 4):

There may be a bug in AAD right now. Another thread also started around the same time as this one: [Empty GUID error when using Azure AD consent flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369841/empty-guid-error-when-using-azure-ad-consent-flow) - According to one comment the AAD team is aware and looking into it.

**UPDATE:**

See my version of this question for the full diagnosis and solution:

[Azure Active Directory passing empty GUID for tenantId with default template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379730/azure-active-directory-passing-empty-guid-for-tenantid-with-default-template)

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: same problem here, it goes wrong logging in with microsoft account. When I create a new user directly in the active directory then there is no error. The bug is not resolved yet then..